# I need help with a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I'm not so great with SQL queries and would like to know if someone would know the correct query to return the information below.  I'm having a difficult time trying to figure this out.  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

#### EXAMPLE DB DATA

```
ID   | DATE                | SHIFT#| LINE# | TOTAL | UPTIME (seconds)
1    | 2019-03-13 10:31:29 | 1     | 1     | 345   | 600
2    | 2019-03-13 10:31:39 | 1     | 2     | 254   | 400
3    | 2019-03-13 10:31:49 | 1     | 3     | 198   | 550
4    | 2019-03-13 10:41:29 | 1     | 1     | 300   | 500
5    | 2019-03-13 10:51:39 | 1     | 2     | 154   | 440
6    | 2019-03-13 10:54:49 | 1     | 3     | 298   | 520
7    | 2019-03-13 15:21:19 | 2     | 1     | 100   | 450
8    | 2019-03-13 15:21:29 | 2     | 2     | 330   | 360
9    | 2019-03-13 15:21:39 | 2     | 3     | 400   | 450
10   | 2019-03-13 15:41:19 | 2     | 1     | 200   | 450
11   | 2019-03-13 15:41:29 | 2     | 2     | 300   | 350
12   | 2019-03-13 15:41:39 | 2     | 3     | 400   | 450
13   | 2019-03-14 10:42:09 | 1     | 1     | 345   | 600
14   | 2019-03-14 10:42:19 | 1     | 2     | 254   | 400
15   | 2019-03-14 10:42:29 | 1     | 3     | 198   | 550
16   | 2019-03-14 10:44:09 | 1     | 1     | 340   | 500
17   | 2019-03-14 10:44:19 | 1     | 2     | 204   | 410
18   | 2019-03-14 10:44:29 | 1     | 3     | 178   | 450
19   | 2019-03-14 15:32:29 | 2     | 1     | 200   | 450
20   | 2019-03-14 15:32:39 | 2     | 2     | 300   | 350
21   | 2019-03-14 15:32:49 | 2     | 3     | 400   | 450
22   | 2019-03-14 15:36:29 | 2     | 1     | 210   | 250
23   | 2019-03-14 15:36:39 | 2     | 2     | 320   | 355
24   | 2019-03-14 15:36:49 | 2     | 3     | 450   | 455
```

I'd like the result of the query to be one line per `DATE`, `SHIFT#`, and `LINE#`.  The `SUM` of the `TOTAL` field and the `SUM` of the `UPTIME` field needs to be included.  I'm trying to get it to look like this:

#### RETURNED RECORD FORMAT

```
DATE       | SHIFT# | LINE# | SUM TOTAL | SUM UPTIME
2019-03-13 | 1      | 1     | 645       | 1100
2019-03-13 | 1      | 2     | 399       | 840
2019-03-13 | 1      | 3     | 494       | 1070
2019-03-13 | 2      | 1     | 300       | 900
2019-03-13 | 2      | 2     | 630       | 710
2019-03-13 | 2      | 3     | 800       | 900
2019-03-14 | 1      | 1     | 685       | 1100
2019-03-14 | 1      | 2     | 458       | 810
2019-03-14 | 1      | 3     | 376       | 1000
2019-03-14 | 2      | 1     | 410       | 700
2019-03-14 | 2      | 2     | 620       | 705
2019-03-14 | 2      | 3     | 850       | 905
```

Comment: Take a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/mcve?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.stackexchange.com&utm_campaign=232465) - then add the pertinent details to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You just need a basic [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with aggregation and [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You can use the [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to truncate the `DATETIME` to just use the `DATE` portion:

```
SELECT CAST([DATE] AS DATE) AS [DATE]
     , [SHIFT]
     , [LINE#]
     , SUM([TOTAL]) AS [SUM TOTAL]
     , SUM([UPTIME (seconds)]) AS [UPTIME]
  FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE), [SHIFT], [LINE#]
ORDER BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE), [SHIFT], [LINE#];
```

Look at the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#e-basic-use-of-the-group-by-clause) on the `GROUP BY` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that appears to give the results you want.

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists table1
go
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  ID INTEGER,
  DATE VARCHAR(19),
  SHIFT# INTEGER,
  LINE# INTEGER,
  TOTAL INTEGER,
  UPTIME  INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (ID, DATE, SHIFT#, LINE#, TOTAL, UPTIME )
VALUES
  ('1', '2019-03-13 10:31:29', '1', '1', '345', '600'),
  ('2', '2019-03-13 10:31:39', '1', '2', '254', '400'),
  ('3', '2019-03-13 10:31:49', '1', '3', '198', '550'),
  ('4', '2019-03-13 10:41:29', '1', '1', '300', '500'),
  ('5', '2019-03-13 10:51:39', '1', '2', '154', '440'),
  ('6', '2019-03-13 10:54:49', '1', '3', '298', '520'),
  ('7', '2019-03-13 15:21:19', '2', '1', '100', '450'),
  ('8', '2019-03-13 15:21:29', '2', '2', '330', '360'),
  ('9', '2019-03-13 15:21:39', '2', '3', '400', '450'),
  ('10', '2019-03-13 15:41:19', '2', '1', '200', '450'),
  ('11', '2019-03-13 15:41:29', '2', '2', '300', '350'),
  ('12', '2019-03-13 15:41:39', '2', '3', '400', '450'),
  ('13', '2019-03-14 10:42:09', '1', '1', '345', '600'),
  ('14', '2019-03-14 10:42:19', '1', '2', '254', '400'),
  ('15', '2019-03-14 10:42:29', '1', '3', '198', '550'),
  ('16', '2019-03-14 10:44:09', '1', '1', '340', '500'),
  ('17', '2019-03-14 10:44:19', '1', '2', '204', '410'),
  ('18', '2019-03-14 10:44:29', '1', '3', '178', '450'),
  ('19', '2019-03-14 15:32:29', '2', '1', '200', '450'),
  ('20', '2019-03-14 15:32:39', '2', '2', '300', '350'),
  ('21', '2019-03-14 15:32:49', '2', '3', '400', '450'),
  ('22', '2019-03-14 15:36:29', '2', '1', '210', '250'),
  ('23', '2019-03-14 15:36:39', '2', '2', '320', '355'),
  ('24', '2019-03-14 15:36:49', '2', '3', '450', '455');

--the solution
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT convert(DATE, [date]) AS [date]
        ,[shift#]
        ,[line#]
        ,total
        ,uptime
    FROM table1
    )
SELECT [date]
    ,[shift#]
    ,[line#]
    ,sum(total) as [SUM TOTAL]
    ,sum(uptime) as [SUM UPTIME]
FROM _cte
GROUP BY [DATE]
    ,[SHIFT#]
    ,[line#]
```

---

```
| date       | shift# | line# | SUM TOTAL        | SUM UPTIME       |
|------------|--------|-------|------------------|------------------|
| 2019-03-13 | 1      | 1     | 645              | 1100             |
| 2019-03-13 | 1      | 2     | 408              | 840              |
| 2019-03-13 | 1      | 3     | 496              | 1070             |
| 2019-03-13 | 2      | 1     | 300              | 900              |
| 2019-03-13 | 2      | 2     | 630              | 710              |
| 2019-03-13 | 2      | 3     | 800              | 900              |
| 2019-03-14 | 1      | 1     | 685              | 1100             |
| 2019-03-14 | 1      | 2     | 458              | 810              |
| 2019-03-14 | 1      | 3     | 376              | 1000             |
| 2019-03-14 | 2      | 1     | 410              | 700              |
| 2019-03-14 | 2      | 2     | 620              | 705              |
| 2019-03-14 | 2      | 3     | 850              | 905              |
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CAST([DATE] AS DATE) AS [DATE], SHIFT, LINE, SUM([TOTAL]) AS [SUM TOTAL], SUM([UPTIME]) AS [SUM UPTIME] FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE), [SHIFT], [LINE]
ORDER BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE), [SHIFT], [LINE]
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add some more information? Code-only answers aren't really seen as acceptable here. Also welcome to DBA.SE.